# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onBeforeSendHeaders') in chrome extension (mv3)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, user-agent, manifest.json

Here is my code

manifest.json

```json
  {
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "2023.4.17",
  "name": "Data protector",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "100",
  "description": "Protects your data!",
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
        {
          "js": [
            "/content.js"
          ],
          "matches": [
            "*://*/*"
          ]
        }
    ],
     "icons": {
        "16": "icon-16x16.png",
        "32": "icon-32x32.png",
        "48": "icon-48x48.png",
        "128": "icon-128x128.png"
  }
}
```

content.js (Where the error happened)

```js
function getVersion() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', chrome.runtime.getURL('manifest.json'), false);
    var manifest = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var version = manifest.version;
    return version;
}


chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function (details) {
    for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
      if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'User-Agent') {
        details.requestHeaders[i].value = details.requestHeaders[i].value + ' Data protector / ' + getVersion();
        break;
      }
    }
    return { requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders };
  },
  { urls: ['<all_urls>'] },
  ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']
);

alert("DATA PROTECTOR | INFO: \n" + "AGENT: " + navigator.userAgent + "\n\nPLATFORM: " + navigator.userAgentData['platform']);
```

I am trying to make an extension that hides your user agent and stuff

I got most of the content.js code from Stackoverflow
I tried adding more permissions but nothing happened

Comment: 1) You must use this API in the background script. 2) With ManifestV3 you can use a blocking webRequest only if extension is installed via policies, so you'll have to make a ManifestV2 extension.